# comparing of two prices using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, bpopup

I just set this jquery code for price compare..

```
          if ([CARTTOTAL]>$125){
              $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                  easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
                  speed: 450,
                  transition: 'slideDown'
              });

          }
```

on page source i found result like this:

```
         if ($2,345>$125){
              $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                  easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
                  speed: 450,
                  transition: 'slideDown'
              });

          }
```

this means [carttotal] gets value...

but its not entering inside if condition...i saw an error in console that $2 is not defined?

Comment: You need to change the value in your if statement to real integers. Try parseInt ..

Comment: okay let me try..Thanks

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting in this question, but apparently edits for Stack Overflow aren't allowed to be less than 6 characters, so my edit wasn't accepted.

Comment: But condition is like this:     if ([CARTTOTAL]  >  $125)  and [CARTTOTAL] fetch cart values..so should i have to write parseint with [CARTTOTAL]???or number??

Comment: 1. you should separate value from currency symbol; 2. you should not rely on the DOM itself to perform such operations, abstract data into a model, or use `data-*` attributest at least [e.g. `data-amount=35`].

Comment: please show me any example or just edit my code  ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ (it is the namespace for jQuery) using .replace and compare numbers (be careful to not to compare strings) with parseInt.

Comment: Okay but its a price..so is  it good to take price without $...?

Comment: Yes, $ is for us in the real life, you can append the dollar sign again once you have the result if you need it.

Comment: Try this:

var price = parseInt([CARTOTAL].replace("$", ""), 10);

if(price > 125)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of integer parse it into float.
The replace function will remove any non-numeric characters except minus sign and period (or decimal point).

```
var compare_value_old="$125";
var compare_value_new=parseFloat(compare_value_old.replace.('/[^0-9-.]/g'));

if (parseFloat([CARTTOTAL].replace('/[^0-9-.]/g')) > compare_value_new)
    { 
      // do something here..
     }
```

Comment: still it show an error in console....  if (parseInt($2,464.81)>125)........$2 is not defined?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your comment :)

Comment: [CARTTOTAL] fetch values when someone added items in cart..but when  i set condition if (parseInt([CARTTOTAL])>125)
    { 
      // do something here..
     }

then it shows error.....$2 not defined.......

Comment: check my changes @RohitSharma

Comment: if (parseFloat($3,974.81.replace('/[^0-9-.]/g')) > compare_value_new) ........i got this in page soruce...its not removing $,.  they are still there..showing error $2 is not defined...

Comment: @RohitSharma put the value inside a quote like '$3,974.81' or "$3,974.81"

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `,` comas and symbols in your numbers. JavaScript uses the English standard (correct me if I'm wrong) that uses `.`(period) as decimal separator. It's a commom problem with French, Brazilian and other sites from countries that uses coma as a decimal separator and dot/period for thousands separator (I'm Brazilian, so I know it from experience).

Some things to do:

1. Replace `.`(periods) per empty strings to remove them and then replace `,` (comas) per `.`;
2. Never use strings (text) to do number comparisons, use `parseFloat()` to convert this values into real numbers;
3. Please do not wait for us to code for you, try it yourself and post your founds editing your question so we can follow-up and help you solve the problem.